# D&D 5e I want to create my own Thieve's Guild

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue

So my character is level 8(Rogue3/Fighter2/Ranger3) and I just bought a big house with a basement and 2 floors and I was thinking to create my own theive's guild in a big city. My group and I are famous in the city for slaying a PyroHydra and a Red dragon, the question is how do I start collecting people fo the Guild?

Comment: Have you discussed this with your DM yet?  Welcome to RPGSE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how to get the most out of an SE formatted site.  A few kinds of questions that don't fit our format [are listed here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: yes,he told me that i will need gold,a good reason to lure the members to fight with me and a good place to train them

Comment: While this doesn't fit the stack model well, we do have a curated list of [forums](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6350/23970) that may be great for this sort of conversation; include din that list is Our Very Own [chat]. Pop in some time! (You'll need 20 rep to chat, which means just one more upvote....)